# How do I replace a closed event loop?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I work mostly in IPython's interactive shell. Sometimes I copy-paste code from the Internet to test it out and work with examples.

If I paste the following code from [this tutorial](http://stackabuse.com/python-async-await-tutorial/):

```
import asyncio

async def speak_async():  
    print('OMG asynchronicity!')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  
loop.run_until_complete(speak_async())  
loop.close()
```

I will close the loop. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.close) says not to use any methods on an event loop after it's been closed. And `async.get_event_loop()` will still return that closed loop.

What should I do if I accidentally close an event loop? I would rather not restart the interpreter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could just [create and set a new event loop for the current context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html);

```
asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
```

Comment: Do I have to set it, or can I use it directly? I figure there's some magic going on that makes me want to set it.

Comment: @leewangzhong Once you set it, the next call to `asyncio.get_event_loop()` will return the new loop and your code will work again without exiting the interpreter.

Comment: I found the answer to the question I meant to ask: The various asyncio functions like `ensure_future` take an optional `loop` parameter, and if that's not provided, it will use the loop in `get_event_loop()`.